# Retrieving a value (phone_number) from a form using Rails and checking if it exists in the database. Send different ajax responses if the value exists

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, erb

Trying to implement a phone number checker. It consists of a user inputting a phone number, submitting the form and checking against a list of phone number records my database and seeing if it exists. I want to send different AJAX responses depending on if the user input exists in the database or not.

I've got the ajax to respond with a message, however when I input a number that exists in the database (e.g. 07780319014), I get the phone-number-not-found response.

Implemented code below:

app/views/phones/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :phone, url: phones_path, remote: true, html: { id: 'phone-number-form'}  do |f| %>
  <div id="phone-number-found"></div>
  <div id="phone-number-not-found"></div>
  <div id="phone-number-error"></div>
  <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
  <%= submit_tag("Check") %>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/phones_controller.rb

```
class PhonesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @phone_number = Phone.where('phone_number = ?', params[:phone_number])
    if @phone_number.exists?
      render 'phone-found'

    elsif @phone_number.blank?
      render 'phone-not-found'

    else
      render 'errors'
    end
  end

  private

  def phone_params
    params.require(:phone).permit(
      :phone_number
    )
  end
end
```

app/views/phones/phone-found.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('Working!');
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-error').html('');
```

app/view/phones/phone-not-found.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('Working!');
$('#phone-number-error').html('');
```

app/view/phones/error.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-error').html('Working!');
```

config/routes.rb

```
resources :phones, path: '4g-promo'
```

Would be greatly appreciated if someone could solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: tell me whether it work or not?

Comment: try with 'phone_number LIKE ?', params[:phone_number]

Comment: Nah still getting the phone-not-found response trying that @jith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking params out in a wrong way

Wrong way

```
 @phone_number = Phone.where('phone_number = ?', params[:phone_number])
```

Right way

```
 @phone_number = Phone.where('phone_number = ?', params[:phone][:phone_number])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Aniket Shivam Tiwari Unfortunately that broke it all together :/ I think its because my phone_number and sim_number fields in the db are strings
db/schema.rb
`create_table "phones", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.string "sim_number"
  end
` 
I'll change them to integers, (which it should be really)

The error I got in the console is a 500 error: can't convert nil into Integer

Comment: what exactly are you getting in params[:phone_number] show me on console .Also do params[:phone_number].class on console and share your result

Comment: So you are getting nil in  params[:phone_number] . So you need to check why it is getting nil

Comment: How do I check that sorry? Checked in chrome console with network, XHR, headers and the form data is:
utf8:✓
phone[phone_number]:45454545
commit:Check

Comment: replace with what i have given as a new answer and tell me whether it works or not

Answer (score 0):

Your form data should all be found within `params[:phone]` hash,

So if you wanted an exact match, then you could do:

```
@phone_number = Phone.where(phone_number: params[:phone][:phone_number])
```

Which will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (e.g. an empty array or array of matches), or:-

```
@phone_number = Phone.find_by(phone_number: params[:phone][:phone_number]
```

Which will return either the record or `nil`.

However, knowing end users, they will format their phone number in different ways, e.g. spacing, dashes, etc. So it won't necessarily do an exact match.

You'll also probably want to use `phone_params` instead of `params[:phone]` in both examples above too.